# R programming (Jackknife)

Tags: machine-learning, r, sampling

Hi I would like to ask how to sample out 50 instances from 150 instances of iris data by using Jackknife. 
Is it possible? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Jackknife is a leave one out method. What do you mean by 50?? Voted to close. -1.

Answer (score 1):

here you go:
http://www.rexamples.com/14/Sample()

sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)